# Pass configuration to IHostedService

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to add a configuration value to an `IHostedService` but do not know how.

This is what I have at the moment:

Startup

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions"));
services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
```

MyOptions

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string MyOption{ get; set; }
}
```

Appsettings

```
"MyOptions": {
  "MyOption": "42"
}
```

MyHostedService

```
public MyHostedService(ILogger<MyHostedService> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    // Where are my options?! :(
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. You got only one thing left to do:

Just use [constructor dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection) with [`IOptions<MyOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1) or related (depending on your scenario) in your [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice):

- [`IOptions<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1)
- [`IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1)
- [`IOptionsSnapshot<TOptions>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionssnapshot-1)

```cs
public MyHostedService(ILogger<MyHostedService> logger, IOptions<MyOptions> optionsAccessor)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
}
```

For more details, see [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options).